# accessing monthly archive from dashboard

Tags: customization

I've been posting to my wordpress site the same way forever, not really knowing much about what I'm doing. It all seems easy.

Recently I've started playing with the site and trying to access parts of the pages other than the actual posts. While in the dashboard I realized that there is no way to access the html in the monthly archive pages...or atleast I can't figure out how one does it.

Can anyone tell me how I can access the html ofthe monthly archive pages from the dashboard?

Thanks for any suggestions anyone can make.

Answer (score 1):

the html for any page is in the template

Often for archives, that is handled by archive.php, but you can make sure that is correct following the template heirarchy
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

That is the basic html, access from appearance->editor from your admin dashboard

Each template has the code, but you may have to dig further. The template will usually call other html, using get_header, get_footer, get_sidebar, etc

This calls in other templates, like header.php, footer.php, etc

And a newer function is get_template_part which can call in other templates, like loop.php, etc

I explain how that works here
http://voodoopress.com/2011/02/get_template_part-in-my-wordpress-theme/